# Lookup df1 column using date value from df2

Tags: python, pandas

I've got two dataframes.

I want to lookup a specific column at a date in df1 and then do something with it in df2:

```
df2['e'].apply(lambda x: df1.loc[x]['Close'])
```

Both are same types:

df1[0] has: `datetime.date(2017, 10, 27)`

df2['e'][0] has similar: `datetime.date(2015, 10, 27)`

Problem:

`df1.loc[date(2017, 10, 18)]` works

`df1.loc[datetime.date(2017, 10, 18)]` doesn't.

How can I lookup at another df using a timestamp or a date field?

-- update: added heads

df1

```
              Open    High   Close
2015-10-18  115.40  116.54  113.99
```

df2

```
       title             e 
0   Article1    2017-10-18
1   Article2    2016-12-20
2   Article3    2016-05-13
3   Article4    2017-10-27
```

Comment: at least show your df1 df2 head

Comment: @Wen i updated the question. thanks!